# Choose the two most similar images from a list of images

Tags: c#, bitmap, compare, tile

I am making a program to convert usual images into tile-based images that old computers (like the Commodore C64) can display.
The dithering and tile palette selection code is already done, using LAB colors and custom bitmap objects (to represent double-precision RGB values).
However, the resulting image is made up of 1000 8x8-pixel tiles, which is impossible to store into the C64's tile RAM (which can store 256 unique tiles only).

I have a List of Bitmaps which contains each the 1000 tiles that makes up the images. I want to combine two images that look similar and repeat until I end up with 256 only. However, I have no idea on how to compare two images, and even worse, how do I select two similar images in the List?

Honestly, I am having problems phrasing my question, since I don't even know how I should ask my problem, or rather, what problems I'm specifically facing. But since I have stated my goal, I hope my question can be understood.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by restricting the number of colors.

Next write a function that measures the difference between two tiles, e.g. by adding up the differences in the color channels.

Now start with a threshold and go through your tiles list1, building up a list2 of tile numbers to use. The first tile index from list1  will always be added to list2, the second only if it is more different from all tiles in list2 than the threshold.

And so on until you either have gone over the limit of 256 tiles in list2 or have processed all tiles in list1.

Repeat using a smaller or larger threshold until you end up with slightly less than 256 tiles in list2.

The list2 you build during the search need not contain bitmaps but integer indices into the original list. When the searches are over build up a list3 as List and a new 2d array that points into the list3!

This will take some time!

Finally when it works in principle you can optimize the measurement function, maybe using unsafe code or lockbits; also consider enlarging the number of colors again. This will take some experimatation.

Sounds like big fun, all the best!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your warm and enthusiastic reply! I will try that :)

Comment: The program is done and working! Since you helped me with the tile reduction algorithm, I think you deserve to see the program yourself. If you don't mind it, I credited you in the program. If you'd rather not, I'll remove it right away.

Here's the program!
https://sites.google.com/site/tarshoduze/home/software/back2basics3

Comment: Cool! congratulations! I certainly don't mind being credited. I did try the same and got rather similar results here. I didn't try to improve yet, but thought about it.. My first step would b to insert a seach for 'smooth' tiles, ie tiles that are pretty uniform and to reserves 5-25% of all tiles for those. This would make all larger areas look much smoother. Then the next step might be to analyze further to recognize subshapes, maybe in 2x2 or 4x4 or even 3x3 tiles within the tiles to find tiles with a darker upper, lower etc half.. But as it stands it is nice already ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the new ideas! I will try it out as soon as I can :)